# How to save entire project in Izotope RX 6

Tags: izotope, files

So I am doing a very large project with hundreds of files, and for a while, I thought that "Save RX Document As..." meant it would save all the currently open tabs. However, when I went back to one, it only opened the exact tab/file I was on when I saved. Is there some other way to save all tabs, or do I need to save each file as its own RX document? I haven't needed to re-edit anything yet, but I like to leave myself a trail to follow, so if something bad happens I don't need to start from the freshly recorded .wav.

I don't use the plugins inside of Ableton for many reasons, but I know that could be the easiest solution.

Comment: Have you contacted iZotope support for their response?

Comment: @Mark yes, when I didn't get an answer I contacted them. When I get home I'll write an answer with their response (which was that there is no way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from Izotope. I sent a message saying:

> Hi, I thought that "Save RX Document As..." meant it would save all
>   the currently open tabs. However, when I went back to one, it only
>   opened the exact tab/file I was on when I saved. Is there some other
>   way to save all tabs, or do I need to save each file as its own RX
>   document? Thank you

and got a response saying:

> Thanks for reaching out to us! Sorry for the difficulty!
>
> Unfortunately you will have to save each of them separately. I’ll be
>   happy to pass this up as feedback to the team though to be considered
>   as an option for future updates!
>
> Please feel free to let me know if you have any questions!